# What Firefox extension can dump HTTP responses?

Tags: http, firefox-addon, dump

I'm familiar with LiveHTTPHeaders and TamperData which can show what is going to be sent to the web server. However, I also want to study the server responses. How can I do this?

Comment: What's the problem?  LiveHTTPHeaders also shows the response headers.

Answer (score 7):

As always: [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843).

Comment: Thanks, but I need a raw HTTP dump. Firebug organizes and parses the data.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [Fiddler](http://i32.tinypic.com/2usx0yg.jpg). It shows all traffic organized per request, and offers multiple ways to view the request and response. Like formatted xml, javascript, post body. It also decodes when needed. If I'm right it also offers an firefox integration addon.

Comment: Yes later versions now integrate with FF, you can configure FF to use fiddler when fiddler is capturing.

Answer (score 3):

[HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647) is one of my favorites.

Comment: +1 for the mentioning this add-on. I just downloaded and tried it it really cool!

Answer (score 2):

Firebug is good.  My preference is [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com).

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Web Developer extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/cs/firefox/addon/60) for Firefox. It has many handy tools and can show you server response and header as well.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you could use [HttpWatch](http://www.httpwatch.com). It will save the complete HTTP response from the server, including all binary content.

There is a free version available, but it is limited to sites in the Alexa Top 20.

** Disclaimer: This answer was posted by Simtec Limited, the makers of HttpWatch **