# cookie created using jQuery(view) not accessible in php(controller) on first attempt

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cookies

I am facing a weird problem on Chrome and Firefox, for a change it works fine IE.
[**Edit1**: Problem occurs at times with IE also]

**Premise:**

- In my homepageView.php, I create a cookie using jQuery, say Cookie1.
- My homepage has link to an application, lets call it App1.
- Cookie1 is accessed in App1's controller and if not found it redirects back to the homepage.

**Problem Statement**

- Clear cache
- Go to homepage(Cookie1 is created)
- Click on link to App1.
- App1 is redirected to homepage(App1 could not access Cookie1)
- Click on App1 link **again**, App1 works fine.

**Snippet**

*homepageView.php*

```
   createCookie('loggedin_ind', true);

   function createCookie(name,value,days) {
        if (days) {
           var date = new Date();
           date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
           var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
        }
        else{
           var expires = "";
        }
        document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";

    }
```

*App1Contoller.php*

```
function index()
{
    if(isset($_COOKIE["loggedin_ind"]))
    {
        //Display App1
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('http://localhost/Sitename');
    }
}
```

Can anyone please suggest why the cookie is not being writter(by jQuery) **or** not being read(by php) in the first occasion only? 
It works fine from the second time.

It also works fine on my localhost, the problem occurs only when the code is migrated to the server.

**Edit2:** I replaced the *cookie* logic with **sessions**, but the problem persists.

**Edit3:** I have a strong feeling this is a **server related issues**. 
I hosted the same piece of code on my hostgator shared hosting and it works fine there, the issue only occurs on my godaddy VDS.
Can anyone suggest how do I check if cookies/sessions are being handled differently on both my servers.
Thanks.

Any help is highly appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: You could check these links - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188837/unable-to-read-cookies-in-firefox-chrome-via-302-redirect-but-works-in-ie

http://forums.asp.net/t/1557515.aspx/1

Comment: make sure the http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php is writeable

Answer (score 4):

I have checked your code and there is no issue in the code , there is the issue in server side

Below is some Step please review it and compare with your existing configuration

**Step 1 :-**

Use output buffering to send output prior to the call of this function, with the overhead of all of your output to the browser being buffered in the server until you send it. You can do this by calling **ob_start()** and **ob_end_flush()** in your script, or setting the output_buffering configuration directive on in your php.ini or server configuration files.

**Step 2:-**

PHP directive **register_globals is set to on** then cookie values will also be made into variables.

**Most Important in your case**

Setting a cookie with a value of FALSE will try to delete the cookie, **you should not use boolean values. Instead, use 0 for FALSE and 1 for TRUE.**

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Hi hRaval ... 
I am using CodeIgniter session instead of cookies now, but in vein ...
Used ob_start and ob_end_flush() with CI Sessions, but dint help ...
Thanks for the  0 vs FALSE input ... shall keep that in mind in the future.
But none of the inputs have helped solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be quite helpful to view the plain HTTP-Headers sent in the first and second request to App1 ...

If the cookie is persistent in both headers, it's a server-related problem. Otherwise I would take a closer look at the browser.

The request should look somewhat like this:

```
GET /app1 HTTP/1.1
Host: default.localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: loggedin_ind=1
```

Here's a list of recommended extensions for Firefox to view the plain HTTP header: [What Firefox extension can dump HTTP responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372446/what-firefox-extension-can-dump-http-responses)
I personally use Firebug for most of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

I has a similar problem with one of my projects. I was posting from my homepage to a php script and then depending on the outcome of the php page, it would be redirected back to my homepage. I would lose the session when redirecting back to my homepage.

Anyway, How are you displaying App 1?

I found my error to be that I was referencing my php script with an absolute url instead of relative, this would cause the php script to start new session, effectively overwriting my previous session.

When I changed my post url from
**http://www.mysite.com/folder/script.php** to 
**/folder/script.php** I would no longer have my session overwritten.

Comment: Hi Jroc .. I have used relative paths and not absolute path, thanks for the suggestion ...